# When the annihilator of each nonzero submodule is prime

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, modules

Let $M$ be a fixed faithful $R$-module over integral domain $R$. Is there any equivalent condition (on  $R$ or on $M $) under which the annihilator of any nonzero submodule of $M$ to be a prime ideal of $R$?

Comment: Sorry if I misunderstand something obvious, but if you fix a single $M$ once and for all, It seems doubtful to ask for conditions on $R$ only, since the answer will  probably depend on your $M$.
Isn't the real question the following one? :  Which are necessary and sufficients conditions on $R$ so that, for all faithful modules $M$, annihilators of submodules of $M$ are prime ideals ?

Comment: Dear GreginGre,  M is a fixed module.

Comment: Then one cannot say anything interesting, see my answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you fix an $M$ once and for all, you cannot say anything interesting, because anything can happen. For example, for $M=R$, it is true for any integral domain $R$: for any nonzero submodule $N$, the annihilator is zero.

If you assume that $R$ is not a field, and if $a$ is nonzero and not a unit of $R$, then $M=R\times R/(a^2)$ is faithful (because an element of the annihilator need to annihilate $(1,\bar{0})$, but has a submodule isomorphic to $R/(a^2)$ whose annihilator is not prime (the annihilator being $(a^2)$. The fact is it is not prime uses the fact that $R$ is an integral domain and that $a$ is not a unit )

If the question is to find necessary and sufficient conditions on an integral domain $R$ such that, for all faithful modules $M$, annihilators of submodules of $M$ are prime, the answer is: $R$ is a  field.

Indeed, if $R$ is a field, this is clear, and conversely, if $R$ is an integral domain but is not a field, then consider a nonzero element $a$ which is not a unit and take $M=R\times R/(a^2)$. As noted before, $M$ does not satisfy the required conditions.